# What does this cron do for each command?

Tags: cron, command

`find /home/root/public_html/_sess -type f -mtime +3 -name 'sess-*' -execdir rm -- {} \;`

I feel like I understand `find` , but I'm not 100% sure what `-type` is, I think that is the file type `f` not sure yet `-mtime` I feel like `-mtime` means a time setting of some sort, and `+3` means maybe that time setting +3? , I feel like `-execdir` `rm` `--` just means remove the files in the directory call `-name 'sess-*'` as well. But again not 100% sure of all the  command elements within and wanted to get clarification.

Comment: try `man find`...

Comment: It's the simple stuff that gets me, thanks, just learning this as you can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `man find` to get information on how Linux `find` works and all the options you can pass to it.

In this case, the command is using the Linux `find` utility to search for files in the `/home/root/public_html/_sess` directory with the following options:

`-file f` - searches for files of filetype `f`, which is regular files (not directories, links, etc)

`-mtime +3` - searches for files modified more than 3 days ago (the + is for more than, -3 would be less than 3 days old)

`-name 'sess-*` - searches for files whose name matches the regex `sess-*` (name starts with "sess-")

`-execdir <command> {};` - executes `<command>` on each file that `find` finds *in the directory that the file was found in*, in this case `<command>` is `rm` to remove the file

So in summary, this job searches for files located in a certain directory, whose names start with a specific string, and which are more than 3 days old, and deletes them.

Comment: Perfect, so I was on the right path in my thinking, thanks so much for sharing your time with me and finding a better answer then I found myself.  Have a great weekend and all the best. (o;